# How to create IBOutlet only for iPAD in a common UIViewController - Universal App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have 2 xibs, one for iPad and one for iPhone.
However, currently I have only one view controller for those 2 xibs that works for both iPhone&iPad.

Inside my iPad Xib I have an IBOutlet that doesn't belong to the iPhone xib.
How should I define that outlet ?
I notice that if I put inside my deallc method, something like this :

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    [outletOnlyForIpad release]
}
```

The app crashes on the iPhone. Apparently cause it doesn't instantiates well on the iPhone. (I hoped it would stay nil, but it's not the case)

I didn't find any preprocessor macro that I can use so I can declare that Outlet only for iPad.
Is the only way to do it is by checking in runTime something like :

```
isIpad()
[outletOnlyForIpad SomeMethodOnTheOutlet]
```

In every place in my controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.  That outlet should be staying `nil`, so sending it a `release` message should be harmless.  Rather than work around the error, I suggest you check where this outlet is being set and fix the cause of the problem.  Are you certain you aren't connecting anything to it in the iPhone nib?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't set the outlet nowhere, it's only connected inside the iPAD Xib. Inside the iPhone there is no such outlet. Though there is an outlet with a similar name, I don't think there is a naming issue here. The weird thing is that at first I see on the iPhone that it is nil, only later for some reason it gets weird value. I checked for memory leaks but couldn't find any.

Comment: Narrow down the locations in your code where this variable is being set.  If you've got a property corresponding to this that isn't being used, remove it.  Run a project-wide search for the variable name.  Set a breakpoint on `loadView` to be certain that you aren't accidentally loading the iPad nib at any point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check at run-time for the device and handle the outlets then if you want separate outlets.

If I create an app with different controls on different devices, I tend to create them programmatically to avoid connection problems such as this.

Answer (score 0):

in your dealloc to avoid the crash on iPhone, and connect the IBOutlet as usual in your iPad xib:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [outletOnlyForIpad release]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you initialize your class, all instance variables are automatically initialised to zero. Thus this is the equivalent of adding:

```
outletOnlyForIpad = nil;
```

To your `init` method.

This `nil` value will be overwritten when the view loads for the iPad but not the iPhone (unless you have other code that sets it). However your `[outletOnlyForIpad release]` crash shows that `outletOnlyForIpad` is not `nil` at this point, which means that *something* has given it a value. You need to find out what this something is - it may be your interface builder file.

Comment: This is not necessary.  In Objective-C instance variables are automatically initialised to `0` (which is equivalent to `nil`).

Comment: I know that - it does no harm, plus it helps him to see that it was definitely `nil` when the class is created and thus helps him to track down where it is being set to a non-`nil` value. Besides, initializing variables is good practice for if he moves on to writing in C or other language which don't `memset()` allocated objects.

Comment: Redundant code is intrinsically harmful if it doesn't serve any purpose.  It is extra code that needs to be read and understood.  Bugs can cause unwanted side effects.  Newbies can become convinced that it is necessary and write a lot of code that they don't have to.

Comment: Writing code in one language as if you were writing it in another is rarely a good idea, cf. "Fortran in any language".

Comment: Lastly, if the variable is being set to some other value somewhere, it will be *after* `init` has been called.

Comment: That doesn't make it a good idea.  Objective-C and C are different languages with different requirements.  What is good Objective-C is not necessarily good C and vice-versa.  If you are working with Objective-C, you should aim to write the best possible Objective-C you can, not the best possible C you can in case you want to learn it later.

Comment: So... avoid Core Foundation then?

Comment: Yes.  If there's a higher-level Objective-C API that does the same thing, in most cases you should use that.

Comment: CoreFoundation is C - not Objective-C. Using C in Objective-C is very common and often necessary. https://developer.apple.com/corefoundation/

Comment: I know all of this.  I think that's quite apparent from what I've been saying - my last comment only makes sense in that context.  Using C in Objective-C when it is *necessary* is an entirely different thing to striving to write good C rather than good Objective-C when you are using Objective-C.